# Quarkus Hibernate not committing transaction

Tags: java, hibernate, quarkus

I have an Hibernate `Entity` class defined in a Quarkus 1.9.2.Final service which I am trying to persist to the database. I inject an `EntityManager` and persist the object and I know that it does insert the record as if I break the app on that line I can query the table and the record is there, however immediately after it exits the method the insert is rolled back.

My Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MyEntityTable",
     schema = "dbo",
     catalog = "MyDB",
     uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "entityNumber")
public class MyEntity implements Serializable {

  private Long entityId;
  private Integer entityNumber;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "entityId", unique = true, nullable = false)
  public Long getEntityId() {
    return this.entityId;
  }

  public void setEntityId(Long entityId) {
     this.entityId = entityId;
  }

}
```

And the class that does the persistence:

```
@RequestScoped
public class Persistor {
  @Inject
  EntityManager em;

  @Transactional
  public MyEntity persistPortfolio(MyEntity m) throws PersistException {
     em.persist(m);
  }
}
```

My config is pretty vanilla:

```
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=mssql
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:sqlserver://db_server;DatabaseName=MyDB;enablePrepareOnFirstPreparedStatementCall=false;
quarkus.datasource.username=user
quarkus.datasource.password=****
quarkus.hibernate-orm.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.generation=none
quarkus.hibernate-orm.log.sql=true
quarkus.hibernate-orm.log.jdbc-warnings=true
```

There are no errors in the log and no indication as to why the transaction is being rolled back. Why does this not commit correctly or at least give an error?

Comment: Could you open an issue in our tracker with a simple reproducer? Looks like something we should look at. Thanks!

Comment: @GuillaumeSmet I believe this issue covers it: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/11929

Comment: FYI, turning off transaction handling resolves the problem. (I realise it's a bad idea - although I don't really need transactions here)